# iPhone 5 ignores launch screen image orientation

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a launch story board, set to work with two sets of size constraints: *Compact-Any* and *Regular-Any*.

All works as expected on *iPad*, *iPhone 6S*, but on other *iPhone*s the launch screen is always shown in portrait, even though the device is in landscape (i.e. the launch screen is on its side).

Is this a trait of earlier phones or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please read [ask], your question isn't suitable for stackoverflow. You may want to try [Ask Different SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) but check their guidelines first as I dont know what is on topic there

Comment: I have read "How to Ask" i am not at all sure why this is not a suitable question to ask here. thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming

Comment: It has everything to do with programming! I am asking how to make sure that the launch screen shows in landscape not in portrait. This is an IOS9, Swift programming issue, considering constraints, size classes and adaptive display.

Comment: You didn't mention the word swift once in your question so it looks as though you have a question about a faulty iphone. Again, in [ask] in the section about question titles, it states "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, **key APIs**, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site. "

Comment: @Karl Jones Swift where?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with Swift indeed, but is a valid question about AutoLayout in iOS. It's just poorly tagged and not very clear.

Comment: Ok, this was not a well thought out question, please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the home screen before you launch your application on the smaller-than-6+ devices. No matter what your device orientation, it's in portrait orientation. So all applications you launch from it launch from portrait orientation.

Open Safari, rotate to landscape, press the home button, then press the Safari button again. Even though your device is physically in landscape mode, and Safari was displaying in landscape mode when you left it, it'll launch in portrait mode and then rotate.

You're getting expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps,

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of the behaviour but it's definitely what Apple wants to happen. So your code isn't at fault.